# loading resource file from different project folder

Tags: java

I have a project of following structure:

```
src
-main
--java
---com
----Example.java
--resources
---main.xml
-test
--java
--resources
---test.xml
```

from Example.java, I can load "**main.xml**" using 
`...
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/main.xml");
...`

but not able to load "**test.xml**".

is it possible to load "**test.xml**" from "**Example.java**".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not load a resource from `src/test` in `src/main`. Because src/test will not be delivered after you have packaged you app. If your class Needs the file, you should think about putting it into `/src/test/java`

Comment: Also: you should strictly separate test and production. Production code should not depend to test code or resources in any way.

Comment: "main.xml" is the default file. however, I have a use case where the user like to provide their own input during the test and changed the behaviour of the project

Comment: @AmarjitThouna Then that is the part of testing and for that your should write code in src/test intead of src/main.

Comment: @AmarjitThouna If you write test code in src/test then you can access these file during testing with the same technique you are using to access main.xml .

Comment: Got it.But from the practicality/ programmatical point of view, is it possible to load "test.xml" from "Example.java"